# Python ValueError: embedded null byte when reading png file from bash pipe

Tags: python, linux, bash

```
from PIL import Image
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

scr = Image.open(Popen.communicate(Popen(['import','-w','0x02a00001','png:-'], stdout=PIPE))[0])
```

Error:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2258, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
ValueError: embedded null byte
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Try first to load raw data into a `BytesIO` container:

```
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

data = Popen.communicate(Popen(['import','-w','0x02a00001','png:-'], stdout=PIPE))[0]
scr = Image.open(BytesIO(data))
```

Comment: `Image.open()` takes a filename.  If you attempt to open a filename with nulls in it on Python 3 you get the error: "ValueError: embedded null byte".  (To see this try `open('x\0y')`.)  It seems to me that wrapping the data in a `BytesIO` won't fix this.

Comment: [Image.open](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.2.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.open) takes a filename (string), pathlib.Path object or a file object. With my tests, it works and I get something like: `<PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=P size=291x374 at 0x7FABD43D1F98>`.

Comment: I stand corrected.  Yes, wrapping the data to make it work like a file object should do the job.

Comment: I used this with `PyArrow` a lot.

Comment: Wrapping data received from memory buffer `fpdf.image(BytesIO(buf)` helped in my case - also buf already is based on BytesIO:
`buf = io.BytesIO();
fig.savefig(buf, format='png');
buf.seek(0);
buf = buf.read()`