# How to read binary file data stored as one of the values of dictionary?

Tags: python, pickle, file-handling, google-colaboratory

I have uploaded my train and test files in colab.

```
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()

uploaded.keys()

with open(uploaded['train_qa.txt'], "rb") as fp:   
    train_data =  pickle.load(fp.read())]
```

I am getting following error:

```
    ValueError   Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-9-afaa1d381444> in <module>()
     ----> 1 with open(uploaded['train_qa.txt'], "rb") as fp:   
     2     train_data =  fp.read()

    ValueError: embedded null byte
```

How do I resolve this? I just want to read the files in colab. I know of other workarounds but how to address this error?

Comment: Duplicate of [Python ValueError: embedded null byte when reading png file from bash pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38979075/python-valueerror-embedded-null-byte-when-reading-png-file-from-bash-pipe).

Answer (score 0):

uploaded already maps to bytes.

So:

```
train_data =  pickle.load(uploaded['train_qa.txt'])
```