# MNIST classifier fails on non-MNIST digits

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, mnist

I just realized that my MNIST digit classifier (a convolutional neural network) fails spectacularly on my own hand-drawn digits, with just around a 55% accuracy (50% on black-on-white images, 60% on white-on-black images).

The result is rather surprising to me, considering that industrial character recognition software is very accurate on completely new characters.

The only explanation I've been able to find online for this is overfitting, which seems unlikely since my model has a 98.4% test accuracy. The other explanation would be that the MNIST data set is not really as general/has a lower dimensionality than one would hope, which seems unlikely. Conversion to grayscale is also not the issue (see comments under Roshin's answer).

Anyone willing to have a look at my model and tell me what's wrong? The testing on my own characters is in the last filled cell.

- https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1nAWoO3Qik0qNOk1I1kzT-V8M_FLY77HH?usp=sharing

Comment: Here is the problem that I saw before. In the MNIST dataset, all digits are in the center of the images. Because of that when I quickly trained a basic model, if the digit was not in the center on the test data, the model classified it wrongly. Later, I tried two things and both of them solved the problem. I centered the digits in the test image. Another solution: I performed data augmentation (translation method) to remove the overcentralized digit from the training data.

Comment: Try data augmentation like shift, rotation, random crops etc.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the lines :

```
# my own hand-drawn characters
with url.urlopen(img) as file:
  x2 = im.imread(file.read())
# average color channels, put in 1-size batch, normalize
x2 = np.array([[[[np.mean(entry)] for entry in row] for row in x2]]) / 255.0
```

You should convert image to grey scale.

```
# my own hand-drawn characters
with url.urlopen(img) as file:
  pil_im = Image.open(file.read()).convert('L')
  img = np.array(pil_im) / 255.0
# average color channels, put in 1-size batch, normalize
```

You should import the `Image` module from `PIL` beforehand,

```
from PIL import Image
```

Comment: Your code gives me an error ("embedded null byte"), but this cannot be the issue -- I'm already converting to grayscale with `np.mean(entry)`. Am I wrong?

Comment: This might with the error : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38979075/python-valueerror-embedded-null-byte-when-reading-png-file-from-bash-pipe

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it misclassifies the same (see the updated notebook). Like I said, I was already converting to grayscale, so that isn't the problem.